# Animating Z-transparency in the game engine for multiple objects sharing the same material

Tags: animation, materials, game-engine, transparency, layers

[image]I have a single material shared between multiple instances of a reference object that is spawned in from a secondary layer. I'm trying to animate the Z-transparency of the sared material but i **don't** want the animation to effect all the object sharing that material.
How can i animate each object's material separately?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried animating the alpha within each of their object colors? In the objects properties panel, each one has an object color. I suggest animating the alpha channel of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can play a material action on each of the objects. The actions play independent from each other even when you use the same mesh and/or material.

You can indeed animate the object color too.

Comment: Since the objects are actually copies of the same object spawned in from a second layer to edit the object color was the right choice.